# How do I access radio button group in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, radio-button

I've added a bunch of radio buttons to the stage in CS5.5, set their "groupName" properties to a common name, but I can't seem to find any tutorials on how to access the group in AS3. All I want to do is get the selected radio's label name.

Can someone help me out?

Comment: radioButtonGroup.selection.label (flex3) or radioButtonGroup.selectedValue

Comment: The groupName for my radio group is "radio_1", but when I put trace(radio_1.selectedValue) I get an error of "Access of undefined property radio_1".

Comment: sorry edited this out.. told you a flex fix in this comment... gimme a sec

Comment: here.. look at this similar question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5532035/flash-radiobutton-how-do-i-get-the-selected-radiobutton)

Answer (score 0):

[RadioButtonGroup.selection](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/controls/RadioButtonGroup.html#selection) is perhaps what you are looking for...

Alternatively, you could implement a custom class that inherits say a sprite, wrap all the radio buttons of a group and add additional tracking properties to control the radio buttons.